# The independence number of directed bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

Assume that we have a directed bipartite graph $G(V,E)$ without any isolated vertex. Is there any bounds on the independence number of this graph? I guess it can be lower bounded by $|E|/2$, where $|E|$ is the number of edges. Is there any other bound?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any useful bounds we can put on the independence number of a graph if we don't know anything specific about the graph. In a [complete graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteGraph.html) we have an independence number of $1$. In a [star graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StarGraph.html) we have an independence number of $|V|-1$. Excluding isolated vertices, these cases cover both extremes.

In a complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ with no isolated vertices, the independence number is $\max\{m,n\}$.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. $\max\{m,n\}$ is true for a complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$. But, do we have other, perhaps tighter, bounds for a general bipartite graph?

Comment: @Hossein, in a general bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ the independence number is at least $\max\{m,n\}$, but it can be at most $|V|-1 = (m+n-1)$ like in the case of the star graph (the star graph on $N$ vertices is the bipartite graph $K_{1,N}$).